# Mostrar todos los elementos seleccionados con .each() JQUERY

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html5

soy muy novato en Jquery y tengo esta duda. ¿Cómo puedo mostrar los tres elementos h6 en un h7? Ya que el único que me sale siempre es el último

> Logro que los elementos se puedan mostrar a través de alert() de forma correcta, uno por uno.

Codigo HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h6>Hola Mundo 1</h6>
    <h6>Hola Mundo 2</h6>
    <h6>Hola Mundo 3</h6>

    <h7></h7>

</body>
<script src="JavaScripts/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</html>
```

Aquí mi código Jquery en donde hago el recorrido con .each()

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
     var fecha = $("h6").each(function(){

        var f = $(this).text()

        $("h7").text(f)


     });
    });
</script>
```

La salida en este caso es solamente de Hola Mundo 3, cuando quisiera que se me mostraran los 3 h6 (Hola Mundo 1 Hola Mundo 2 y Hola Mundo3)

Espero me puedan ayudar. GRACIAS :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Estás reemplazando en una única etiqueta h7 definida, un modo de resolverlo es crear dinámicamente las etiquetas que vas a necesitar.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
     var fecha = $("h6").each(function(){

        var f = $(this).text()

        //$("h7").text(f)
        $("h7").append('<span>'+f+'</span>');


     });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>

    <h6>Hola Mundo 1</h6>
    <h6>Hola Mundo 2</h6>
    <h6>Hola Mundo 3</h6>

    <h7></h7>

</body>
```

Comment: Muchas Gracias. Duda resuelta :)